# Echo out html set number of times - php

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table

I'm creating quite a complex html `<table>` layout and at this early stage it quite time consuming for me to copy and paste each `<tr>` in order to generate dummy content.

My idea was to specify a dummy `<tr>` as a `$var` and then output that x number of times using a function as below:

```
$html = "<tr>//content</tr>";

function dummy_html($html, $times){

        $i = 0;
        for ($i <= $times) {
            echo $html;
            $i = $i++; 
        }
    }

    echo dummy_html($html, 5);
```

But this is returning a parse error on the `for` line any idea why that might be ?

Comment: $i = $i++;  should be             $i++;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: also your function call should be dummy_html($html, 5); in place of     echo dummy_html($html, 5);

Comment: Do an correct for loop (shown below) or use an while loop (just while instead for, the rest stays)

Comment: -1 for failing to check the manual page for correct syntax.

Comment: You'd figure after 195 questions asked, at least the 196th would show some previous research effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a function already

```
echo str_repeat($html,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is incorrect.  It should be something like:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= $times; $i++ ) {
   echo $html;
}
```

**Update**

**@Your Common Sense**'s solution is better: `str_repeat` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 1):

`for` should use the notation: `for (set arguments, conditions, command to run at the end of the loop)`, therefor should be:

`for($i = 0; $i <= $times; $i++)`

Also, I would recommend using `str_repeat` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)